# DIVI Theme customizer changes not applied on existing pages and designs are not shown on the front

Tags: custom-post-types, images, themes, css

I'm using the Divi 4.8 theme on a localhost created by WAMP Server.

The changes I make using the theme customizer menu are updated correctly in the preview screen (header, background colour, logo size, etc)

But when I view the frontend none of these changes are saved or updated.

There are no plugins installed, and refreshing the page makes no difference.

Only the changes I made using the theme customizer aren't being displayed.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? (Press F12 then go to the Console tab on most browsers, and then refresh the page.) Can you switch to another theme and see if the same problem happens with other themes?

Answer (score 0):

https://intercom.help/elegantthemes/en/articles/2207396-website-looks-different-in-builder

go to Divi > Theme Options > Builder > Advanced in the Divi Theme Options.

First clear the cache using the black colored Clear button and then disable the option for Static CSS File Generation